# ASP.Net MVC 5 get attribute routing values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I switch from the old attribute routing library to the bundled asp.net MVC 5 routing. But now my `lang` route value is `null` in the `Application_AcquireRequestState`

```
// rootcontroller.cs       
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
[Route("{lang}")]
// old attribute routing worked:
// [GET("/{lang}")]
public ActionResult Index(string lang =null)
{
    return View();
}

// global.asax
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var handler = Context.Handler as MvcHandler;

    if (handler == null)
       return;
    var routeData = handler.RequestContext.RouteData;

    var lang = routeData.Values["lang"];   // null instead for example 'de'
    // ... set current culture
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute routing in MVC 5 uses a special key named "MS_DirectRouteMatches" which contains a list of `RouteData` elements. I am not sure why they did this as it seems that only one `RouteData` element is possible. So you need to check for this key and use its first value if it exists.

```
var routeData = handler.RequestContext.RouteData;

if (routeData != null)
{
    if (routeData.Values.ContainsKey("MS_DirectRouteMatches"))
    {
        routeData = ((IEnumerable<RouteData>)routeData.Values["MS_DirectRouteMatches"]).First();
    }
}

var lang = routeData.Values["lang"];
```